# Multiple lines titles in toolbars header in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to set the toolbar title text in multiple lines but it shows only in single line and after 15 character text is going to be Eclipse in Android. Please help me guys.

```
 Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        if(!getSupportActionBar().isTitleTruncated()){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(job.getJob_title());
        }

            Spannable text = new SpannableString(job.getJob_title());
            text.
setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(MainApplication.getIconColor()), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(text);

            Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
            upArrow.setColorFilter(MainApplication.getIconColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Comment: Please fix formatting to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/product_details_toolbar"
    style="@style/style.toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/double_height_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_details_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_normal"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        android:maxLines="2" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

try this