# How to split activity label into multiple lines in android

Tags: android

How to display activity label text in two lines in android

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Transaction"
        android:label="Karthik (ID:6734) Associated Asraya : India">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Want to split the line "Karthik (ID:6734) Associated Asraya : India" in to two like this

Karthik (ID:6734)

Associated Asraya : India

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Please provide some more details about your case: do you want it split in toolbar or in launcher?

Comment: I want to split the label in toolbar

Comment: You'll find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252635/multiple-lines-titles-in-toolbars-header-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines titles in toolbars header in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252635/multiple-lines-titles-in-toolbars-header-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** : Define a custom TextView with max line 2 in your toolbar layout.

**Step 2** : Define the label text in String resource file and put `\n` where you want to want to split the text.